# How to get following output in c#?

Tags: asp.net

Create a function which will take two parameter as integer, and will return output like this -:
xxxxxx
xoooox
xoxxox
xoooox
xxxxxx

example-:
i have a function in which i am passing two parameter like (5,6), now first parameter 5 will means 5 rows and 6 means 6 column and it should return array or something with the following output, don't forget that parameter value can be change so output should be according to the parameter but in the same format. How to do this?

Comment: someone asked me this question, and i don't know how to do this.

Comment: @AnilThakur The Question is not clear and the title doesn't reflect the actual problem, we are more than happy to help you but not solve the quiz on behalf of you

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is something like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> foo(int lines, int columns) {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>(lines);

        for (int l = 1; l <= lines; l++) ret.Add(new String('x', columns)); 

        return ret;
    }
```